# Angular Mat-multiple-select, getting the data from the dropdown list

Tags: angular, data-binding

```
HTML:
  <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose terms</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="termlist" multiple>
  <mat-option required *ngFor="let term of terms" [value]="term.termName"  
  >
  {{term.termName}}
  </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-flat-button color="primary" 
  (click)="openSelectComponent()">Continue</button>
```

Typescript file:

```
     termlist = new FormControl();
       terms: Term;
       constructor(private termHttpService: TermHttpService, private router: 
       Router) { }
       ngOnInit() {
       this.termHttpService.get().subscribe(result => {
      this.terms = result;
      console.log(result);
    });

  }
  openSelectComponent() {
    this.router.navigate(['/termselected'])
  }
}
```

So the main point is how do I get the values from the multiple select(terms) and pass them out to the next component?

So the data from here:

https://gyazo.com/49bbcddf17bee2f44d7a1a4579568ee0

How do I get into these selected values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a event `OnSelectionChange` on select -

> your HTML

```
 <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Choose terms</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="termlist" multiple>
  <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="getValues($event)" required *ngFor="let term of terms" [value]="term.termName"  
  >
  {{term.termName}}
  </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-flat-button color="primary" 
  (click)="openSelectComponent()">Continue</button>
```

> your component.ts

```
 getValues(event: {
    isUserInput: any;
    source: { value: any; selected: any };
  }) {
    if (event.isUserInput) {
      if (event.source.selected === true) {
        console.log(event.source.value)
      } else {
        console.log(event.source.value)
      }
    }
  }
```

> **Note**: event.source.selected === true defined the `checkbox` is checked

Comment: I got the terms logged in console now, thank you fine sir :)

Comment: @AnttiKarjalainen If it helps you to get what you want.please accept the answer as accepted so it will help other users.

Comment: Yes, it solved the case. Now I am going to move to the part where to get the userInput values to a new component

Comment: for the communication between components you can use `services`

Comment: Would u use local storage within the service? Is it a good way to store data for passing it to another component?

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

term.html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Select Term</mat-label>
  <mat-select name="term" 
     [(ngModel)]="selectedTerm" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let term of termsList"
         [value]="term">{{term.name}}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

term.component.ts

```
import {ITerms} from "app/shared/model/term.model";
termsList: ITerms[];
originalTerm: ITerms[] = [];
selectedTerms: ITerms[] = [];

openSelectComponent(){
    this.originalTerm = [];
    if(this.terms.length > 0){
       let data: ITerms[] = [];
       this.terms.forEach((ele) => {
          data.push(ele.term);
          this.originalTerm.push(ele.term);
       });  
    }
}
```

term.model.ts

```
export interface ITerms {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
}
export class Terms implements ITerm {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public name?: string,
    ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<mat-select multiple (ngModel)]="mySelection">
```

mySelection has to be declared in your component.

```
public mySelection: NgModel;
```

Comment: if you want to share your selected data with other components in another route, so you have to persist this selection in a service or other way like redux. https://github.com/angular-redux/store

If the destination component is in the same route (same page), you have to emit the selected "mySelection" with EventEmitter: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: Thank you sir! Goin to try with EventEmitter.

Answer (score 0):

put it in the export class

```
termlist = new FormControl();
```

if you wanna console you can do:

```
this.result{
    selectList: this.termlist .value
}
```

last:

```
console.log(this.result);
```